# Application takes KDE down with it when it dies

Tags: xorg, kde, crash

How is this possible? I am using Toggl Desktop, stable channel, under KDE, and about 50% of the time, after I do

```
xrandr --output DP1 --auto --primary --output eDP1 --off
```

Toggl Desktop crashes soon afterwards, *and brings down the whole of KDE and the Xorg server* with it. Even though Toggl Desktop had been crashing without bringing down the entire desktop environment sometimes, I didn't realise it was Toggl Desktop causing the problem until just now, when I clicked on it and then it brought down the desktop.

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` shows an apparently normal shutdown (no segfault in the X server itself).

Here are some relevant lines from `journalctl -xb`:

```
Feb 25 17:26:43 laptop audit[25435]: USER_AUTH pid=25435 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=4 msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="robin" exe="/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop audit[5042]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 pid=5042 comm="ksmserver" exe="/usr/bin/ksmserver" sig=11
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop abrt-hook-ccpp[25440]: Process 5042 (ksmserver) of user 1000 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop audit[21187]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 pid=21187 comm="QXcbEventReader" exe="/home/robin/opened/toggldesktop/TogglDesktop" sig=11
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: QXcbEventReader[21187]: segfault at 7efed8052629 ip 00007efed8052629 sp 00007efed6c18da0 error 14 in locale-archive[7efed8569000+6952000]
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop abrt-hook-ccpp[25442]: Process 21167 (TogglDesktop) of user 1000 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop bluetoothd[920]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop bluetoothd[920]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop org.kde.kded5[4035]: kscreen: Failed to retrieve current config:  "Backend invalidated"
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop pulseaudio[25443]: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {86b8923b1590429fb4426072e954d8de}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Successfully made thread 25447 of process 25447 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop pulseaudio[25447]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop audit[11243]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 pid=11243 comm="QXcbEventReader" exe="/usr/bin/konsole" sig=11
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop audit[5174]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 pid=5174 comm="QXcbEventReader" exe="/usr/bin/xembedsniproxy" sig=11
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop audit[5098]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 pid=5098 comm="QXcbEventReader" exe="/usr/libexec/kdeconnectd" sig=11
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: QXcbEventReader[11243]: segfault at 7f853c39eda9 ip 00007f853c39eda9 sp 00007f853a205ca0 error 14 in locale-archive[7f853c851000+6952000]
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: QXcbEventReader[5174]: segfault at 7fd5d844fda9 ip 00007fd5d844fda9 sp 00007fd5d608bd20 error 14 in locale-archive[7fd5d8902000+6952000]
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: QXcbEventReader[5098]: segfault at 7f9b463b7da9 ip 00007f9b463b7da9 sp 00007f9b4421eca0 error 14 in locale-archive[7f9b4686a000+6952000]
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: Pid 5163(QXcbEventReader) over core_pipe_limit
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop kernel: Skipping core dump
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop polkitd[999]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.50, object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop abrt-hook-ccpp[25451]: Process 5084 (kdeconnectd) of user 1000 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop abrt-hook-ccpp[25452]: Process 11242 (konsole) of user 1000 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop org.kde.kded5[4035]: kscreen: Failed to retrieve current config:  "Backend invalidated"
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Successfully made thread 25467 of process 25447 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop abrt-hook-ccpp[25451]: Failed to create core_backtrace: waitpid failed: No child processes
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Successfully made thread 25490 of process 25447 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb 25 17:26:48 laptop rtkit-daemon[972]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
```

Comment: About 1 minute after this, abrt logged an MCE, and this was associated with the CPU core and package overheating.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to diagnose this issue by attaching to ksmserver from gdb on tty2, but unfortunately, that setup somehow managed to crash all the ttys apart from tty1 when ksmserver died!

However, I have figured out that the cause of the crashing applications seems to be [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49450), which will be fixed in the next Qt version.